# jquery/javascript: function(e){.... what is e? why is it needed? what does it actually do/accomplish?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

```
$('#myTable').click(function(e) {
    var clicked = $(e.target);
    clicked.css('background', 'red');
});
```

Can someone explain this to me, and explain why e is needed, and what it actually does..

Comment: Looks like we need an answer that explains how the anonymous function attains a value for `e`. This would be outside jQuery, but a javascript specific answer.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Using `e` is just a short for `event`. You can pass any variable name you desire.

```
// would work just the same
$('#myTable').click(function(anyothername) {
    var clicked = $(anyothername.target);
});
```

You can check out more on [jQuery's handling of events](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/01/working-with-jquery-13-new-event-object.html).

Comment: It is also worth noting this is not specific just to jQuery, but to native events in javascript as well.

Comment: ah, i didn't know it was just a variable... so, what's the purpose of that variable if I'm not using it anywhere else in my script but those 2 places? i don't get what it holds... what tells it the information to hold?

Comment: @android.nick even though you may not use it explicitly jQuery needs it. Imagine the `click` scenario. jQuery needs to know the action performed and the item the action was performed on. So even if you're not using the variable it's used internally. But you can call `$('#myTable').click(function() { ... });` just as well.

Comment: I had the same question exactly

Comment: I am trying to understand the same question, so it is kind of like "this" because it refers, to itself, without e the function callback target would not be able to attach to #mytable?

Answer (score 10):

One benefit to having `e` (the object that raised the event) allows you to prevent the propagation of default behaviors for certain elements.  For example:

```
<a id="navLink" href="http://mysite/someOtherPage.htm">Click For Info</a>
```

renders a link that the user can click.  If a user has JavaScript disabled (why?  I dunno), you want the user to navigate to someOtherPage.htm when they click the link.  But if they have JavaScript enabled, then you want to display a modal dialog and not navigate away from the page.  You would handle this by preventing the default behavior of the anchor/link and displaying the modal as such:

```
$("#navLink").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();  //this prevents the user from navigating to the someOtherPage.htm
  $("#hiddenDiv").dialog({
    //options
  });  //show the dialog
});
```

So having that parameter available allows you to, among other things described in other answers, prevent the default behavior of the selected element.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am trying to understand the same question, so it is kind of like "this" because it refers, to itself, without e the function callback target would not be able to attach to #mytable?

Answer (score 8):

I'm speaking in theory as to I'm no expert but I achieved the desired result by using he the little (e) which doesn't have to be an e lol

I figured it out. It's a way of passing the same event from one function to another.

In simpler terms. I wanted to make the page navigation an elastic scroll function, however, I wanted the page to navigate by hover "and" I wanted the same navigation to be clickable upon certain conditions. I also wanted the same dynamic navigation from other click events that were not links. To keep the current target and still use the navigation function I had to set the little (e) because jQuery will lose the scope of $(this) as the same target of the function lol. Here's a quick example.

```
function navigate_to_page(e){
var target = $(e.currentTarget).attr('href'); //--This is the same as $(this) but more static to bring out of it's scope
    $('html, body').animate({
    'scrollTop':$(target).offset().top-0,
    'scrollLeft': $(target).offset().left-$(window).width()*0.0}, 2000, 'easeOutBounce');
}
```

Don't let the gibberish confuse you. It's just a simple page scroll animation. The thing to pay attention to is the **e.currentTarget**. **e** is our variable and **currentTarget** is a jQuery equivalent to $(this) so those together is a Globular $(this) function.
Now I call it by another function with condistions like so

```
$('#myNavigationDiv a').on('mouseenter', function(e){
    if($(myCondition) === true){
        return false;
        }else{
        navigate_to_page(e);
        }
    });
```

See how the little (e) linked everything together?

Now you can substitute (e) to (whateveryouwant). By calling e in both functions it matched **e**.currentTarget and you can apply this to whatever detailed specific functions you need and save yourself LITERALLY pages of code lol

Comment: @TheCarver You downvoted because he used LOL even though the answer had good input?  Yeah, you're grown up because grown ups point out "childish" things while ignoring the main point.

Comment: @Snorlax - Who said I was a grown up? I just don't write childishly on a serious website that needs well-written, English answers for our international friends to understand. LOL is slang and not everybody understands slang. It also means nothing is more countries than it means something, and using it in places that are not funny is pretty pointless if you ask me. I can downvote if I think the question has been written poorly - go check the rules.

Comment: I'm not arguing your right to downvote, I just think it's even more childish to downvote the comment because you don't agree with 1% of the content in it and you make that more important than the majority of the post.  Most international people understand what "lol" is so that's not even an issue.

Comment: @Snorlax - If you're not arguing my right to downvote, then why are we having a debate about it?! Imagine if everybody on this site wrote in slang, their local slang, and abbreviated everything - this site would be unbearable to read and translate. "Most international people understand it" - this is incorrect and I would like to see your research/proof on that statement.

Comment: @Snorlax - In Sweden, they don't use "LOL" but instead use "ASG". In Malasia, they use "ha3". The French use "MDR (mort de rire - dying of laughter) but, as Europeans, probably understand LOL, also. In Thailand, it's "555". In Africa, "LWKM". Now, imagine if people came here and wrote their own local slang in answers. Or, imagine going to one of their popular sites, like SO, and translate their content with abbreviations. I can understand him using it once, maybe, to denote laughing, maybe, even though it's not internationally recognised, but he's abusing them like fullstops.

Comment: Up-voted because this answer was helpful to me. While it is perhaps not ready for inclusion into a technical manual, it was articulate and clear, with relevant examples. I come here to become a better developer, not to complain about colloquialistic literary eccentricities. And while I can appreciate a writing style that is sensitive to the linguistic diversity of the potential audience, I am reluctant to offer criticism on behalf of the international community, acknowledging that I can't possibly know whether they do or do not understand "lol". LOL! 

Thank you, BrianIAK, for this answer!

Answer (score 6):

It's the formal parameter for the function.  jQuery will pass in an event object when the function is called.  This is used to determine the target.  As noted in the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Types#Event), jQuery will always pass an event object even when the browser (e.g. IE) doesn't.

In this case, the target tells you which element was originally clicked.