# PHP/JS Form reload prevention

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I've tried atleast a dozen different attempts at solving the problem of submitting form data to my database without reloading the page and scrolling to the top. With every attempted solution it continues to submit and scroll to the the top of the page in both chrome and safari.

```
//JAVA
<script type="application/javascript">
function doitall()
{
function validateHistory()
{
var x=document.getElementById("hist").value;
if(x==""}

   function(e)  {
       e.preventDefault();
       // Great isnt it
   return false;

   }
   </script>

// FORM
                <form action="search.php" onsubmit="return doitall();">
                     <td  bgcolor="#242424"><input class="textinput" type="text" value="" name ="hist" id ="hist" placeholder="Address" size="50"/></td><td bgcolor="#242424"><input type="hidden" value= name = id = size="100"/></td>
                    <td  bgcolor="#242424"><input type="hidden" value=<?php echo $num;?> name ="number" id ="number" size="50"/></td>
                    <td  bgcolor="#242424"><input type="hidden" value= name = id = size=""/></td>

                    <td bgcolor="#242424"><input type="submit" value="Submit onsubmit="return doitall();" class="buttonx"/>
```

Comment: Your first part isn't Java - it's Javascript. It's *crucial* that you understand that those aren't the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have a typo in your *JavaScript*:

```
function validateHistory() {
    var x=document.getElementById("hist").value;
    if(x==""){ // You made a typo here
       function(e)  {
           e.preventDefault();
           // Great isnt it
           return false;
        }
    }
}
```

You also have a ton of malformed HTML. Try using [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: What is `e` by the way? And from where will it come?

Comment: As far as I know, it's the event as an object, and the `preventDefault();` method tells it to not to perform the default action. [More information here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535996/jquery-javascript-functione-what-is-e-why-is-it-needed-what-does-it-ac) @Imdad