# How to create nxm HTML5 canvas Grid of objects (colored squares)?

Tags: javascript, css, html, math, canvas

I'm trying to create a grid (matrix) of squares in a given area `<canvas>` with n columns and m rows, and an option to set a spacing between the squares if desired. The grid should fill squares with random coloring.

I'd also like to add a zoom function, so the colored squares will appear much bigger in a region that is double-clicked.

Can anyone suggest a good method to generate the grid and assign random colors to the squares? If you can suggest how to create the zoom effect too that would be SUPER :)

I'm new to canvas, so any method help would be great!
Thanks

Comment: Did you actually try anything?

Comment: Not yet Zeke, I thought would ask for ideas on method first. If i can find method which sounds reasonable I'll try that. Can waste a lot of time just trying stuff all the time.

Comment: What about generating a 2D array of square objects? Drawing would be iterating thought the array positioning an element based on where they are in the array. For random colors use `Math.random()` to generate random RGB values (from `0` to `255`).

Comment: Sounds reasonable spencer. I guess i could create a loop for the columns and another loop inside it for the rows, and populate the grid that way.

Comment: Once I have a grid of squares that are say 10px x 10px how would I handle the zooming? Does canvas have some kind of perspective or camera features?

Comment: No such features, zooming will actually be resizing and repositioning the squares.

Comment: @Shomz Actually that's not entirely true. You can use `context.scale()`.

Comment: @sidewaiise The canvas has features that allow transformation on the context of the canvas: `ctx.translate()`, `ctx.scale()`, `ctx.rotate()`, etc. Here is a good site on how to use them: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-transform-translate-tutorial/

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek thanks for that, will check it out. If i figure it out in a short amount of code I'll post it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek You're right, thank you. Completely forgot about it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like from the comments you @Spencer Wieczorek have the padded-cell drawing worked out.

The key to the other part of your question is using transforms:

- determine the point from which you want to scale (doubleclicking): `var scalePtX,scalePtY`.
- save the untransformed context state: `ctx.save();`
- translate by (1-zoom)*scalePoint: `ctx.translate((1-zoom)*scalePtX,(1-zoom)*scalePtY)`
- scale by the zoom: `ctx.scale(zoom,zoom)`
- draw cells using coordinates as if they were untransformed: `fillRect`
- restore the context to its untransformed state: `ctx.restore()`

Here's the important code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/e8bfg3h4/

```
function draw(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate((1-zoom)*scalePtX,(1-zoom)*scalePtY);
    ctx.scale(zoom,zoom);
    ctx.globalAlpha=0.25;
    for(var y=0;y<rows;y++){
    for(var x=0;x<cols;x++){
        ctx.fillStyle=colors[y*cols+x];
        ctx.fillRect(x*(w+padding),y*(h+padding),w,h);
    }}
    ctx.globalAlpha=1.00;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(scalePtX,scalePtY,10,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
}
```

Comment: mark, thanks you've filled all the holes I've just been experiencing :). Will implement your code shortly and see how it plays. Thanks for such a detailed response.

Comment: I've attempted to augment a section of your code - the part that handles the zooming, and I'm having trouble interpreting your handleMouseDown(e) function. Why have you incorporated the 'e' object in this function? It's just confusing me a bit.

Comment: have answered my own question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535996/jquery-javascript-functione-what-is-e-why-is-it-needed-what-does-it-ac

Comment: @sidewaiise As you've discovered, the `e` in the mouse handler holds an event object.  The clientX & clientY properties of that event object hold the current position of the mouse.  Cheers!