# understanding the usage of e inside carasoul.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey guys i was just going through the code of [carousel.js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/carousel.js#L44) and i am a little bit confused , now we it comes to attaching events i ofte see code as follows ::

```
$('a').click(fuction(e){
    if(e.target.targetNode == $(this)[0])
   //do something
});
```

I am still a bit confused , who is passing the `e` ? WHO really is passing that e inside the function ?

also in the plugin code i see things like the below :

```
Carousel.prototype.keydown = function (e) {
  if (/input|textarea/i.test(e.target.tagName)) return
  switch (e.which) {
    case 37: this.prev(); break
    case 39: this.next(); break
    default: return
  }
```

an event handler is attached like so :

```
  this.options.keyboard && this.$element.on('keydown.bs.carousel', $.proxy(this.keydown, this))
```

another example is here :

```
  Carousel.prototype.pause = function (e) {
    e || (this.paused = true)

    if (this.$element.find('.next, .prev').length && $.support.transition) {
      this.$element.trigger($.support.transition.end)
    }
    this.interval = clearInterval(this.interval)
    return this
  }
```

Who is passing `e` inside these functions , from where is it coming from ? i have absolutly no clue , i have been using JS for a while now , but this still baffles me . can somebody really clear this doubt for me once and for all ?

**P.S.**  I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535996/jquery-javascript-functione-what-is-e-why-is-it-needed-what-does-it-ac) answer on SO , but it does't answer the questions i have asked . I understand that `e` is in a way a object with differentv properties that we can access.

Answer (score 1):

The functions you are referring to are called callback functions. Parameters for those are passed from within the function that is calling them ( in your case .on() or .click() )

to better illustrate how callback functions work here is an example

```
function customFunction ( param1, callbackFunction ) {
    var response = "default response";
    if (param1 === "hello") {
        response = "greeting";
    }
    callbackFunction(response);
}

customFunction("hello", function(e) {
    console.log("this is " + e);
}); // > this is greeting
```

As you can see you are able to pass a function as parameter to another function.  If you do so the the parent function can call this function internally as `callbackFunction` is called within the `customFunction`. 
When we call `customFunction` we provide two parameters ("hello" string and anonymous function) which are then processed as described inside the `customFunction` with callbackFunction (in our case anonymous function we passed) being called after all other computations are done with the parameter we got inside the `customFunction`.

Comment: I still don't understand how e Is passed internally ! , anyways , small correction , `"this is greeting"` ! instead of `"this is hello"` in the console.

Comment: i did expand my answer a little, maybe this helps.